# Как сгенерировать slug для таблиц Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Нашел такой пакет https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable поставил, но ничего не проиходит((

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    //slug
    use Sluggable;

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходи из описания, то тебе нужно:

1. Добавить в миграции поле `$table->string('slug')`;
2. Использовать трейт `HasSlug`;
3. В моделе `Category` создать метод

```
public function getSlugOptions() : SlugOptions
    {
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('что переименовать')
            ->saveSlugsTo('куда сохранять');
    }
```

4. И дальше уже из поля `slug`, доставать нужное тебе значение